# I accidentally created a tag -- how can I delete it?

Tags: support, tag-deletion

I was playing with few options and accidentally created this meta tag [dfgdfgdg](/questions/tagged/dfgdfgdg), which I shouldn't have. How can I get rid of it? Do I need a moderator to delete it?

[image: Tag]

Comment: I think the tag will die after a while if you delete your question.

Comment: [This link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags) says that it would take 6 months.

Comment: Six months is fine, it leaves ample time to retag bad questions `[dfgdfgdg]` before closing them. A meme is born. Or not.

Comment: The tag is gone!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Tags that have no questions are automatically deleted every night at midnight, so you can just remove the tag from your question. The privileges page you linked to is talking about tags that exist on only one question -- if after 6 months the tag is still only on that one question, it's assumed to not be a very good tag and gets removed

Comment: Thanks for your response. Ok. I had already deleted that sample question I posted along with this tag. I will delete this question as well.

Comment: Please don't delete *this* question as it provides valuable information!

Comment: Is this still true? Just confirming because someone created a tag that shouldn't exist (it's a typo). If I remove the tag from the question (so no other questions have the tag) will it still get deleted?