# Burninate the [old-school] tag on SO

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags, tag-block-request

OK, just saw the [old-school](/questions/tagged/old-school) tag today with six instances.  We should probably burninate that one.  Let's not let it get any more populated.

Answer (score 4):

There's only 6 instances; just edit them out. Orphan tags are deleted [daily](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101262/i-accidentally-created-a-tag-how-can-i-delete-it/101263#101263)

Comment: That will still leave the tag to be used or recreated, it needs to be done away with.

Comment: @LanceRoberts It doesn't leave it around, "orphan tags are deleted daily". It could be recreated if a user had enough rep, yes; are you asking for it to be blacklisted? It doesn't seem popular enough to need it

Comment: @Nightfirecat Get rid of them both and add better tags?

Comment: @Night, if a question is stripped of tags it acquires the `untagged` tag.

Comment: Yeh, it's not a big deal, just stupid tag I'd rather not see come back.  I'll get around to editing it out at some time.