# Can tags that were clearly created in error be removed?

Tags: support, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I accidentally created a tag — how can I delete it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101262/i-accidentally-created-a-tag-how-can-i-delete-it)

I was looking at the newest tags and found one, [avascript](/questions/tagged/avascript) on SO.  Looked like a mistype for [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), but wondering if someone had actually come up with a scripting language by that name.  A Google and Bing search found nothing by that name.

Since no question is tagged with this tag, it seems likely to me that someone typo'ed and then later came back and corrected his or her question with the correct tag.

My question here is, since there doesn't seem to be a way to propose the tag for deletion (or at least I couldn't find a way), should there perhaps be a way?

Comment: Tags are deleted within 24 hours after removal of the tag from the last remaining question. If the tag still exists on the next day, something weird is happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A tag that is not in use on any posts get cleaned up daily.

Tags used only once also get cleaned up after a set duration.

You can find more information in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48418/140548)

Comment: Looked for an answer earlier and this question didn't come up -- if it had I wouldn't have asked this.  Oh, well.