# Delete [visual-studio-2011] tag

Tags: support, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I accidentally created a tag — how can I delete it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101262/i-accidentally-created-a-tag-how-can-i-delete-it)

Can the [visual-studio-2011](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2011) tag be deleted?

I asked a vs11 question.

[looks at shoes and whistles]
     Then in a typo-induced fit I didn't see the 2011 tag, so I created it & added a wiki.
[/end whistling].

Someone kindly re-tagged my question with the appropriate [visual-studio-11](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-11) tag, but pollution remains.

Comment: If there are no question with that tag, it will get automatically deleted after a while if I remember right.

Comment: Hopefully quickly...i'm trying to wipe away the shame!

Comment: Yeah, it's looking like VS 11 won't make it in time to be released in 2011...

Comment: FWIW, I've had to nuke that tag four or five times now.  People have gotten so used to year-based version numbers that the simple "11" is throwing them off.

Comment: Why don't we just make `[visual-studio-2011]` a synonym of the *correct* tag, `[vs-11]`? That way, no one can ever accidentally create it again in error, and if they try to use it, their question will be automatically retagged with the *correct* tag? I don't see why that would offend even naming purists. (cc @Charles)

Comment: @CodyGray, it'd probably be more appropriate to wait until we know if the final product name is going to be "11" or "2012".

Answer (score 6):

The tag will automatically be removed within 24 hours since it has no questions, at which time your suggested edit for the wiki will get rejected if it's still pending at that time.

I wouldn't worry about it. It's not like people are running around looking for mistakes people make...