# Remove the recently created tag "javscript"

Tags: discussion, tags

I've found the [javscript](/questions/tagged/javscript) while going through my daily contribution, where a user was suggesting a wiki for it.

It is for sure a typo when selecting tags for a question, and currently there are no questions associated with it.

> [image]

I am asking to remove it before it gets used.

Comment: related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133575/delete-javacript-tag

Comment: @ajax333221 I get now that tags are auto-deleted, but 24h is more than enough to have a user using it. just saying... :)

Comment: I was going to say "that never happens, though - people don't just mindlessly follow the autocomplete for tags!"... and then it actually happened.

Comment: Oh, look; another one. Maybe this tag should be blacklisted, unless that incurs some kind of grievous performance hit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Orphan tags are deleted [daily](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101262/i-accidentally-created-a-tag-how-can-i-delete-it/101263#101263), so if you just ignore it it'll be gone tomorrow (assuming nobody uses it by then, but that seems unlikely)